# How to create a frame and fill it with a segmented control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to create a frame and fill it with a segmented control.  How would i do this???

Comment: Please re-state your question so it's clearer what you'd like assistance with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by filling a frame with a segmented control, you mean you want to add a segmented control as a subview of another view with a specific frame, you could do this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(X_ORIGIN,Y_ORIGIN,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
UISegmentedControl * seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[viewYouWantToAddTheControlTo addSubview:seg];
[seg release];
```

Does that help?

Comment: I want to put the segmented in the frame